# Is a script to allow a user to make a subdomain under the domain point to an IP address possible?

Tags: php, ip

How would this have to be created if possible? Can it only be created in cPanel, or is it possible to make a script for users to use without logging into cPanel that allows them to make their domain?

Comment: cPanel is a 'script' to - written in perl. if it can be done in perl it can be done in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be possible depending on your hosting / server setup:

1. Add a wildcard domain CNAME record `*.yourdomain.com`;
2. Use a rewrite rule to direct all traffic to `anything.yourdomain.com` to a php script to handle the requests;
3. Do whatever you want in your php script: Use a `header` redirect, present another page in an iframe, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A *subdomain* is just an entry in the DNS server configuration. Likely you'll be able to update the configuration by adding a bunch of lines in a file, or a new file altogether. This really depends on the DNS server software, maybe the one you use also has an API to be updated via a TCP socket.

Also if the target IP is shared (and thus you use name-based virtual host), or it's a different one, maybe you want an HTTP server listening on the port 80 on that IP.